# Track counts of company names on pages

Tags: google-analytics

I'm new to Google Analytics, is it possible to use it to track a dynamic page that generates a list of companies? In particular, how many times they appear on the page?

Example, imagine the user inputs some data on a web page, submits, and it basically generates the following results list of company names:

```
Company Name One
Company Name Two
Company Name One
Company Name Three
Company Name Two
Company Name Three
Company Name Two
```

What is the best way to track this results page ?  I want to know "Company Name One" showed twice, "Company Name Two" showed three times etc. and keep a rolling tally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could probably be done by passing by custom dimensions or via Google Analytics event.

If it were me I might just fire an event that passes back the company names as comma separated values and then use excel or another tool to analyze the data.

So I might send an event that looks like:

```
<script>

ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'Company Tracker',
  eventAction: 'Submit',
  eventLabel: 'Company 1, Company 2, Company 1, Company 3, Company 4'
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks I'm not sure how I could get the event label populated. Would I use JS to populate it as variables or could I set it up to read and count the number of times the name appeared on the page with GA ?

Comment: You can use Google Tag Manager and the datalayer in order to control and fire the "company" events.

Comment: As Emirodgar mentions you could use something like Google Tag Manager to create what is called a dataLayer, and populate the event label using the info contained in the dataLayer.   Some decent tutorials on the web for this stuff, and do a better with setup than I can provide in a comment.